# Redirecting URL regardless of language

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to write a redirection that looks the following:

User accesses '/en/subscription' -> Redirected to '/en/newsletter'
User accesses '/de/subscription' -> Redirected to '/de/newsletter'
etc.

It's supposed to work for any language that might be implemented and return a 301. I've looked into the documentation but I couldn't find something conclusive.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please ask in Serverfault, as this is as setup question rather than a programming question.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^(/\w\w)/subscription$ $1/newsletter permanent;`